# Add a default text to a textarea in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, textarea

can anyone help me how to add default text into my comment textarea. I do no how to override the comment-form in drupal 7.  This is what i tried

function  hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
   {

```
 $form['comment-form'] = array(
 '#default_value' => t('Some default text'),
 '#title' => t('Field Title'),
'#type' => 'textarea',
 '#required' => FALSE,
 '#rows' => 10,
```

);

Here in my case the text area is located into in form.

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hook `THEMENAME_form_comment_form_alter` in your `template.php` file.

Looks like everything else you're doing is right but in the wrong hook.